# Change assembly default namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, excel-addins

I renamed my project but the default namespace has stayed the same as the original.

If I go to project properties the default namespace field is disabled, so I can't change it!

However I need to change it because when I try to read resource files the wrong names are being requested, I assume because the namespace is wrong.

How can I change this value? I can't find it in any of the files in the solution.

I even changed the COM Guid in case this was stored in the registry somewhere!

Comment: If VS isn't letting you change it, close the project and open up the proj file in your favourite text editor... it won't be disabled there...

Comment: That did it - I had searched for the name before but it didn't show, not sure why. Thanks!